# What are good bounds on ratios of subdeterminants?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, real-analysis, inequalities

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix and $A_i$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by dropping the $i^{th}$ row and column. Then what are some good bounds on the value of $\frac{det(A_i)}{det(A)}$ ?

- Using the fact that the eigenvalues of these two matrices interlace each other I can say that, $\frac{1}{\lambda_{max} (A) } \leq \frac{det(A_i)}{det(A)} \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_{min} (A) }$

  Can this be bettered? 
  Feel free to assume something more about $A$ if you need!

---

I was wondering if one can somehow use the inequality that $\vert det (B) \vert \leq \prod_{i=1}^{i=dim(B)} \vert column_i (B) \vert _{l^2}$

Comment: You should assume A is nonsingular.  Also, inspired by the idea of looking at a related ratio of the area of a face of a parallelipiped to its volume, I doubt that much more can be said.

Comment: Clearly, both bounds are sharp: take for $A$ a matrix whose minimal or maximal eigenvalue equals $1$ and the corresponding eigenspace splits off as an orthogonal summand. (I mean, is a coordinate line.)

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Simpler put: take a diagonal matrix.

Comment: You can also use convexity of this function to get some bounds.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: By some transformations
$$\frac{\det(A_i)}{\det(A)}=\frac{1}{a_{ii}-v^TA_i^{-1}v}$$
where $v$ is the $i$-th row of $A$ without $a_{ii}$.